# Adicionando vários IDS dentro de um array?

Tags: javascript, react, mongodb, mongoose

```
const [pergunta, setAddPergunta] = useState([])
async function pegarId(_id) {setAddPergunta(_id) 
    console.log(_id)}
 <tbody>
    {getPerg.map((pe, i) => (
        <tr key={i}>
            <th scope="row">{pe.area}</th>
            <td
                onClick={() => pegarId(pe._id)}
            >
            {pe.pergunta}<br></br>
                <strong>Responder: </strong> <label> Sim </label> <input
                    value={false}
                    onChange={e => setResposta(e.target.value)}
                    type="radio"
                /> <label> Não </label> <input
                    value={true}
                    onChange={e => setResposta(e.target.value)}
                    type="radio"
                />
            </td>
        </tr>
    ))}
</tbody>
```

O que está acontecendo quando uso o `click` para pegar o `ID` da pergunta?

```
{
    "pergunta":["5d6fa2fad1af7d3070ea7e8e"],
    "_id":"5d71078671e10832c8e87e5d",
    "responsavel":"Pedro",
    "time":"5d6fe08e1814790dd084219a",
    "createdAt":"2019-09-05T13:03:02.445Z","updatedAt":"2019-09-05T13:03:02.445Z",
    "__v":0
}
```

O que eu queria que acontecesse é que salvasse o `array` de uma pergunta no banco.

```
{
    "pergunta":'[
        "5d6fa2fad1af7d3070ea7e8e", 
        "5d6fa86bd1af7d3070ea7e8f", 
        "5d6fa881d1af7d3070ea7e90"
    ]',
    "_id":"5d71078671e10832c8e87e5d",
    "responsavel":"Pedro",
    "time":"5d6fe08e1814790dd084219a",
    "createdAt":"2019-09-05T13:03:02.445Z","updatedAt":"2019-09-05T13:03:02.445Z",
    "__v":0
}
```

Já use o método `push` para adicionar outro `array` e nada como fazer para pegar o `click` os `IDS` e adicionar dentro do `array`?

Comment: Ola pedro, **apenas uma sugestão,** vale a pena você dar uma olhada nesta publicação do [meta], pois sua pergunta da forma que foi escrita esta caindo em um dos items abordado nela, e isso pode fazer você ser negativado - [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/3774) =D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```js
async function pegarId(_id) {
    setAddPergunta([...pergunta, _id]) 
}
```

Esses 3 pontinhos é o `spread operator` ele funciona pra objetos também, o que ele ta fazendo e esparramando os valores que já existem dentro de um novo array e adicionando um novo valor aos que já existem e como se você fizesse isso

```js
pergunta =  [...pergunta, _id]
```

E no `react` o estado é imutável ele não muda então se você tivesse conseguido utilizar o `push` você estaria violando essa imutabilidade porque você estaria editando o estado atual, e dessa maneira que eu mostrei você esta criando um novo estado, em memoria é outro array, que é a forma correta de se trabalhar com estado no `react`.

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo.

Comment: blz, alterei a responsta coloquei uma explicação pra realmente vc entender e não só copiar.